# d3 -- how to create multi color border

Tags: d3.js

I need different colors for a border for a d3 project. Here is my border code that works:

```
        //Create a Border
    d3.select("svg").append("rect")
        .attr("x",0)
        .attr("y",0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("style","fill-opacity:0; stroke:black;stroke-width:2px");
```

I need to add red and green and can not figure out how do it?

Comment: Are you wanting to color the different sides (borders) of the rectangle with different colors? I don't think svg:rect allows this possibility. Should you draw four separate lines forming a rectangle instead? You could then assign each line a separate color. But this may not be what you are asking...the question is not very clear, at least to me.

Comment: this is what i want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/9877/amp55/

Comment: If you want a multi-coloured border like from box shadow effect with SVG rectangles, you will need to create multiple rectangles, one for each colour.  Each rectangle only has one stroke colour.  However, if you want the border to be around the entire SVG, you can use HTML/CSS border effects on the SVG as a whole (just not on shapes inside it).

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this tentatively because I do not know your level of familiarity with D3. So, here is a minimal skeleton that I hard-coded for expediency but could easily be generated automatically with known height, offsets, etc.

```
data = [
    {x:0, y:0, w: 110, h:100, color:"green"},
    {x:10, y:10, w: 90, h:80, color:"red"},
    {x:20, y:20, w: 70, h:60, color:"yellow"}
];
d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x",function(d) { console.log(d); return d.x;})
    .attr("y",function(d) {return d.y;})
    .attr("width",function(d) {return d.w;})
    .attr("height",function(d) {return d.h;})
    .attr("style",function(d) {return "fill-opacity:0; stroke:" + d.color + ";stroke-width:2px";});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use **[d3.scale.ordinal()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal)**,and you can specific the color 
*d3.scale.ordinal().range(["green", "red","blue"])*,if you want random color use **[d3.scale.category10()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10)**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/3TKdJ/1/)**

```
 var data = [
        {x:0, y:0, w: 110, h:100},
        {x:10, y:10, w: 90, h:80},
        {x:20, y:20, w: 70, h:60}
    ];
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["green", "red","blue"]);
    d3.select("body").append("svg").selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
        .attr("x",function(d) { console.log(d); return d.x;})
        .attr("y",function(d) {return d.y;})
        .attr("width",function(d) {return d.w;})
        .attr("height",function(d) {return d.h;})
        .attr("style",function(d,i) { return "fill-opacity:0; stroke:" + color(i) + ";stroke-width:2px";});
```